# Entity Framework, LINQ Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How to loop through the Items below and update the Field which have empty values with the value (!)
Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.threading.task to
> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Respositories.AssignmentMasterData>

```
using (SUPEntities db = new SUPEntities())
{
    IEnumerable<AssignementMasterData> masterDatas = null;

    masterDatas = db.AssignementMasterDatas
                    .Where(m => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.CreatedDateTime) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(criteria.FilterStartDate)
                        && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.CreatedDateTime) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(criteria.FilterEndDate)
                        && (m.AssignmentNoteNumber == criteria.AssigmentNumber || criteria.AssignmentNumber == null)
                        && (m.BaseCourseId == criteria.courseId || criteria.CourseId == 0)
                        && (m.AccountNumber == criteria.AccountNumber || criteria.AccountNumber == null)
                        && (m.ReferenceNumber == criteria.ReferenceNumber || criteria.ReferenceNumber == null)
                        && (m.FacultyCode == criteria.FAcultyCode || criteria.FacultyCode == null)
                        && (m.Processed == criteria.Processed)
                        && (m.ClassNumber == criteria.ClassNumber || criteria.ClassNumber == null))
                    .ForEachAsync(t => t.AssignmentNoteIdentifiedClasses.Select(e => String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Category)? "(!)": e.Category));
                
}
```

Comment: ForEachAsync returns Task but you are not awaiting it, you can just use sync method (ForEach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `.Include( m => m.AssignmentNoteIdentifiedClasses )` to bring-in related data in a single query, this is **much faster** than loading each set of related `AssignmentNoteIdentifiedClasses` in your for-each-row loop.

  - [This is also known as the "N+1 Problem" in ORMs](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/07/common-entity-framework-problems-n-1/).
- You don't need to use `TruncateTime`.

  - In fact, you *shouldn't* because that will mean your query isn't SARGable.
  - Avoid functions in SQL predicates.
  - Instead, just round `criteria.FilterStartDate` down to the start-of-day in application code and compare it normally with `m => m.CreatedDateTime >= filterStart`.
  - Similarly, `FilterEndDate` should be rounded-up and then compared like so: `m => m.CreatedDateTime < filterEnd`

    - Always use exclusive upper-bounds. It makes *everything*, especially date-range predicates, much easier to deal with.
- You don't need inline `&&` in your `Where`. Use additional separate `.Where()` clauses instead. They'll be added to the same (single) `WHERE` clause as separate `AND` terms.
- I assume EF Core isn't sophisticated enough to recognize the "`NULL`-means-ignore" anti-pattern for optional search predicates, in which case **DON'T USE the "`NULL`-means-ignore" *anti-pattern* IN AN `IQUERYABLE<T>` PREDICATE!**

  - This is bad for so many reasons: namely because query execution-plans are based on the *structure* ("shape") of the SQL query and *not* on parameter values, so the same cached execution-plan for non-`NULL` parameters will be used when some, or even all parameters are `NULL` - which is a problem. Also, be sure to read up on [parameter sniffing](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-2016-parameter-sniffing/).
  - Instead **build your query** by using `IQueryable<T>`'s Linq extensions and reassigning to itself.

    - e.g. `IQueryable<T> query = db.Etc; query = query.Where( e => etc );`
    - Each `.Where()` is added as an `AND` condition. If you want to build-up an `OR` condition [then use `PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

---

```cs
DateTime filterStart   = criteria.FilterStartDate.Date;
DateTime filterEndExcl = criteria.FilterEndDate  .Date.AddDays(1);

using (SUPEntities db = new SUPEntities())
{
    IQueryable<AssignementMasterData> query = db.AssignementMasterDatas
        .Include( m => m.AssignmentNoteIdentifiedClasses )
        .Where( m => m.CreatedDateTime >= filterStart   )
        .Where( m => m.CreatedDateTime <  filterEndExcl ) // Exclusive upper-bound.
        .Where( m => m.Processed       == criteria.Processed )
        .Where( m => m.ClassNumber     == criteria.ClassNumber )
    ;

    if( criteria.AssigmentNumber != null )
    {
        query = query.Where( m => m.AssignmentNoteNumber == criteria.AssigmentNumber );
    }

    if( criteria.AccountNumber != null )
    {
        query = query.Where( m => m.AccountNumber == criteria.AccountNumber );
    }

    if( criteria.CourseId != null && criteria.CourseId.Value > 0 )
    {
        query = query.Where( m => m.BaseCourseId == criteria.CourseId );
    }

    if( criteria.ReferenceNumber != null )
    {
        query = query.Where( m => m.ReferenceNumber == criteria.ReferenceNumber );
    }

    if( criteria.FacultyCode != null )
    {
        query = query.Where( m => m.FacultyCode == criteria.FacultyCode );
    }

    if( criteria.ClassNumber != null )
    {
        query = query.Where( m => m.ClassNumber == criteria.ClassNumber );
    }

    List<AssignementMasterData> rows = await query.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    List<String> categories = rows
        .SelectMany( r => r.AssignmentNoteIdentifiedClasses )
        .Select( String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Category)? "(!)": e.Category) )
        .ToList();

    return categories;
}
```

---

The above can be simplified by adding a new extension-method (make sure you use `Expression<Func<...>>` and not just `Func<>` so that EF can still interpret the query:

```cs
public static class MyQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereIfNotNull<T,TValue>( this IQueryable<T> query, TValue? value, Expression<Func<T,Boolean>> predicate )
        where TValue : struct
    {
        if( value.HasValue && value.Value != default(TValue) )
        {
            return query.Where( predicate );
        }
        else
        {
            return query;
        }
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```cs
// `criteria` is now named `c` for brevity.

DateTime filterStart   = c.FilterStartDate.Date;
DateTime filterEndExcl = c.FilterEndDate  .Date.AddDays(1);

using (SUPEntities db = new SUPEntities())
{
    IQueryable<AssignementMasterData> query = db.AssignementMasterDatas
        .Include( m => m.AssignmentNoteIdentifiedClasses )
        .Where( m => m.CreatedDateTime >= filterStart    )
        .Where( m => m.CreatedDateTime <  filterEndExcl  ) // Exclusive upper-bound.
        .Where( m => m.Processed       == c.Processed    )
        .Where( m => m.ClassNumber     == c.ClassNumber  )
        .WhereIfNotNull( c.AssigmentNumber, m => m.AssignmentNoteNumber == c.AssigmentNumber )
        .WhereIfNotNull( c.AccountNumber  , m => m.AccountNumber        == c.AccountNumber   )
        .WhereIfNotNull( c.CourseId       , m => m.BaseCourseId       ​  == c.CourseId        )
        ​.WhereIfNotNull( c.ReferenceNumber, m => m.ReferenceNumberr     == c.ReferenceNumber )
        ​.WhereIfNotNull( c.FacultyCode    , m => m.FacultyCoder         == c.FacultyCode     )
        ​.WhereIfNotNull( c.ClassNumber    , m => m.ClassNumber          == c.ClassNumber     )
   ;

    List<AssignementMasterData> rows = await query.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    List<String> categories = rows
        .SelectMany( r => r.AssignmentNoteIdentifiedClasses )
        .Select( String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Category)? "(!)": e.Category) )
        .ToList();

    return categories;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, about the error message:

You are trying to assign the wrong type to your `masterDatas` variable.
You declare it as a `IEnumerable<Respositories.AssignmentMasterData>`, but the `ForEachAsync` at the last line will return a `Task`, hence the error message.

See the `ForEachAsync` signature:

> public static System.Threading.Tasks.Task ForEachAsync (this
> System.Linq.IQueryable source, Action action);

Secondly. You want to return an `IEnumerable<Respositories.AssignmentMasterData>`

If you can content with a synchronous method, you could do it this way:

You will need to some point transform your `IQueryable` into an `IEnumerable`. A call to `AsEnumerable()` does that. Then you need to replace some values. So you need to project your collection using a `Select`.

```
using (SUPEntities db = new SUPEntities())
{
    var masterDatas = db.AssignementMasterDatas
        .Where(m => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.CreatedDateTime) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(criteria.FilterStartDate)
            && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(m.CreatedDateTime) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(criteria.FilterEndDate)
            && (m.AssignmentNoteNumber == criteria.AssigmentNumber || criteria.AssignmentNumber == null)
            && (m.BaseCourseId == criteria.courseId || criteria.CourseId == 0)
            && (m.AccountNumber == criteria.AccountNumber || criteria.AccountNumber == null)
            && (m.ReferenceNumber == criteria.ReferenceNumber || criteria.ReferenceNumber == null)
            && (m.FacultyCode == criteria.FAcultyCode || criteria.FacultyCode == null)
            && (m.Processed == criteria.Processed)
            && (m.ClassNumber == criteria.ClassNumber || criteria.ClassNumber == null))
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(a =>
        {
            a.AssignmentNoteIdentifiedClasses = a.AssignmentNoteIdentifiedClasses
                .Select(e =>
                {
                    e.Category = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Category) ? "(!)" : e.Category;
                    return e;
                })
                .ToList(); // Depending on the type of AssignmentNoteIdentifiedClasses, ToList() might be replaced.
            return a;
        });
    return masterDatas;
}
```

Comment: Of course, now this code blocks the thread instead of keeping it async.

Comment: It will depend on the way the returned IEnumerable will be enumerated.

Comment: "It will depend on the way the returned `IEnumerable` will be enumerated." - no, that is incorrect. An `IEnumerable<T>` can **only** be enumerated synchronously, not asynchronously - that's why `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` exists. Using non-async Linq methods will _always_ use synchronous (i.e. blocking) enumeration.  To do this in a non-blocking fashion you need to replace `AsEnumerable()` with `await ...ToListAsync()` as well as adding `Include( a => a.AssignmentNoteIdentifiedClasses )` - and only after that intermediate result is loaded _then_ you can synchronously process it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but then I'm confused: the original code used `ForEachAsync`, which returned a `Task`. If I understood correctly you say this is asynchronous. Then I say with my answer that we don't know yet if it will be asynchronous or not, because we don't know how the `IEnumerable` will be used. What if `ForEachAsync` is called on this `IEnumerable`. Are we not returning to the original asynchronous situation?

Comment: You **cannot** use `ForEachAsync` with an `IEnumerable<T>`, only 
`IQueryable<T>` (or `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`). They're entirely different interfaces. When you use `ForEachAsync` with an `IQueryable<T>` then the query will be evaluated asynchronously. When you use `AsEnumerable()` with an `IQueryable<T>` then the query will be evaluated synchronously (_not_ asynchronously).

Comment: Yes, you are right! I completely forgot! even `ForEach` is not an `IEnumerable` method. It went out of my head! Thanks.

Comment: My method is an asynchronous. The function evaluation requires all threads to run.  I am looking for how to handle this situation without disrupting the method. Laurent Gabiot solution works if my method was not asynchronous.